# CKEditor - add ckeditor to ajax created textarea

Tags: ajax, ckeditor

Is it possible to add ckeditor to textarea which is created with ajax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It works the same way as regular textarea.

[`CKEDITOR.replace(element);`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.replace)

Comment: I added textarea via ajax to some div and after that I called CKEDITOR.replace('.ckeditor'); (this textarea hass class ckeditor) and it is not working.

Comment: and how can I get on jquery click content from that textarea?

Comment: I get content with this code: CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData() but if i change text in that editor result is the same text before change.